# Wrong output value Using C# in VSCode (warning: CS7022)

Tags: c#

I'm currently new to C# and busy learning the basics and discovered this problem when starting: [C# Beginner Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMwCU.png)
But the output is Hello, World!: [Hello, World!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbupb.png)

Before Anyone asks did I remember to save changes when changing the text: Yes...I pressed CTRL + S.

(PS: If anyone could also help me fix the "warning: CS7022" Error I am Getting, it may be the problem for the wrong output problem I am facing.)

(Additional Information: Working on C:/ but storing data on E:/, Installed .NET SDK for VSCode (LTS version), Installed C# Extension and Code Runner on VSCode, Windows 11)

I copied the Error/Warning text and googled it but nothing really came up. I also searched "Wrong output C#" but nothing also.

Comment: From the warning it looks like you have some more code (another file) that has the `Console.WriteLine("Hello, World")` code and that's get's executed and treated as your entry point. Share the full project and code not as images but text.

Comment: @PawełŁukasik I see, there is another file with "Hello, World!" called Program.cs

So we know what the problem is so there is no need to share the full project, Thank you really...Is there any way to fix and chnage this so it prints the right thing?

Comment: Why not just change the message in that `Program.cs` file? Or delete it, then it should pick your file with your entry point.

Comment: Yes, I did it and it works, but for future projects when I want to print two things like I just tried on two separate files how do I solve this? I would like to note that I started using C# a few hours ago so I'm completely new. Although I did learn Python a few months ago

Comment: If you've just started learning C# (good for you), find a tutorial and learn from it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.